# Need Regex pattern to validate password pattern

Tags: c#, regex

We need to validate password against following pattern.
 “Xabcdef99*” [1st char uppercase, 2nd to 7th chars lowercase, 8th  to 9th digits and last char a symbol ]

Can someone provide me Regex for the same? How I can validate following password against that Regex in C#.

Userpcs12* --> Valid

Testeur333 --> Invalid (because last char is not symbol)

userpcs12* --> Invalid (because first char is not uppercase)

Comment: Why would _any_ security system mandate _where_ capital;lower-case letters; and symbols reside in a password?  Talk about predictable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this,

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{6}\d{2}[~!@#$%^&*]$
```

Add the symbols you want inside the last character class.

or

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{6}\d{2}\W$
```

`\W` matches any non-word character. Change this to `[\W_]` if you treat `_` as special charcater.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z][a-z]{6}\d{2}\W$");
        Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsMatch("Xabcdef99*"));
        Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsMatch("Xabcdef99$"));
        Assert.IsFalse(regex.IsMatch("Testeur333"));
        Assert.IsFalse(regex.IsMatch("userpcs12*"));
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_.  See the other answers here for examples

Answer (score 0):

Check this regex:

```
\A\p{Lu}\p{Ll}{6}\d{2}[~!@#$%^&*]\z
```

`\p{Lu}` matches uppercase letters

`\p{Ll}` matches lowercase letters

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dU5nA1/2) on regex101